# How can i write one array from javascript file to another new js file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, savefiledialog

hi i have one array in my js file.I want to write this array and save it as newfile.js in a specific path is that possible??

**My Js file with array**

```
    var myArray = new Array();

    myArray[0] = "News";
    myArray[1] = "Sports";
    myArray[2] = "International";
// i want to save this myArray to a new js file.
    var jsondata= JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

//Node Js code

```
    fs.appendFile("/chat.js",jsondata, function(err) {
          if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          } else {
          console.log("The file was saved!");
          }
          });
```

Please help me

Comment: javascript is a client side language that can't directly access the file system from a browser

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: The only way would be accessing Flash/AIR API from Javascript to write on file system or send it to a server side script that creates a file on the server.

Comment: Are you planning to run this on a browser?

Comment: in my xcode.......yup on mobile browser

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer** : probably not.

**Long answer** : it depends of the context.
Javascript is usually running in a sandboxed browser environment. For security reasons, there is no API defined to interact directly with the host file system.

In the other hand, a Javascript engine (think spidermonkey, V8) can be embedded just like any other scripting language. The host application in this case may or may not allow you to manipulate the filesystem. An example is node.js, or Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Possible...unless you are using node.js

```
vsr fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('newfile.js',[your array],function(){
    if(err) return console.log("something went wrong");
    console.log("File created");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use node(Js on browser can not write file), you can save the file content as:

```
"var myArray="+ JSON.stringify(array)+";";
```

The final file content will like this:

```
var myArray=["News","Sports","International"];
```

Comment: i want to write this array in new js file  example i want to write this in data.js file .So when i open Data.js i can see my aray in JSON format